# unittest: same test class with mutliple datasets

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest

#### setup

i am trying to run the same [`unittest.TestCase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase) on mutliple datasets. my setup is about the following (simplified as much as i could):

```
from unittest import TestCase, TestSuite

class MyTest(TestCase):
    def __init__(self, a, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(methodName="runTest", *args, **kwargs)
        self.a = a

    def setUp(self):
        # something stateful that depends on self.a in the real use case
        self.count = 0

    def tearDown(self):
        del self.count

    def runTest(self):
        self.test_a()

    def test_a(self):
        self.count += 1
        self.assertGreaterEqual(self.a, 0)

test_data = tuple(range(5))
test_cases = tuple(MyTest(a) for a in test_data)

def suite():
    test_suite = TestSuite()
    test_suite.addTests(test_cases)
    return test_suite
```

#### this works

i can run those 5 tests with [`TextTestRunner`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TextTestRunner)

```
from unittest import TextTestRunner

TextTestRunner().run(suite())
```

that works fine.

#### failed attempt 1

i would like to run it using [`unittests.main`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.main):

```
from unittest import main

main(verbosity=3)
```

which runs fine at first (the numbers `0, 1, .., 4` pass the test) but then a 6th argument is passed to the funciton: the `str`ing `'test_a'`; here the test fails of course.

#### failed attempt 2

but the ulitmate goal would be to run it using [`unittest.TestLoader().discover()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestLoader.discover) (which would be run from a different python module):

```
from unittest import TestLoader
from pathlib import Path


FILE = Path(__file__)
HERE_DIR = Path(FILE).parent
loader = TestLoader()
discovered_suite = loader.discover(start_dir=str(HERE_DIR), pattern=FILE.name)
TextTestRunner().run(discovered_suite)
```

if i do that the line `loader.discover(...)` again initializes `MyTest` six times instead of five; the last time again with the `str`ing `'test_a'`.

#### question

how can i set up this test with one `TestCase` and multiple parameters in a way i can run it using [`unittest.TestLoader().discover()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestLoader.discover)?

---

i finally found out what might help: adding a [`load_tests`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#load-tests-protocol) method to the module:

```
def load_tests(loader, standard_tests, pattern):
    return suite()
```

small caveat though: the test is still initialized a 6th time as stated above... how can this be avoided?

because if `MyTest` took more than one argument:

```
class MyTest(TestCase):
    def __init__(self, a, b, *args, **kwargs):
        ....

test_cases = tuple(MyTest(a, a) for a in test_data)
```

this would make the test crash when the loader tried to pass `'test_a'` as only argument:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i gave up and went for a mixin-type approach (here an example with 2 members: `a` and `b`):

```
class MyTest:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def setUp(self):
        # something stateful in the real use case
        self.count = 0

    def tearDown(self):
        del self.count

    def runTest(self):
        self.test_a()

    def test_a(self):
        self.count += 1
        self.assertGreaterEqual(self.a, 0)


class Test0(MyTest, TestCase):
    a = 0
    b = 0


class Test1(MyTest, TestCase):
    a = 1
    b = 1


if __name__ == "__main__":

    main(verbosity=3)
```